# getting error when trying to execute an Sql command

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

DataReader throwing an error message when trying to execute an command in my vb.net page
And the code throwing error is:

```
Dim connectionString As String
Dim connection As SqlConnection
Dim sql As String

connectionString = \\\connection string\\\
connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

sql = "select * from jb_jobs where city='Los Angeles' "
connection.Open()
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sql.ExecuteReader()
```

And the error is:
'ExecuteReader' is not a member of 'string'
How to resolve this???

Comment: sql is not SqlCommand. You need to create sqlcommand.

Comment: You probably want to look at SqlCommand objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
sql = "select * from jb_jobs where city='Los Angeles' ";
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
    var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: this vb.net you using c#

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
connection.Open()
Dim cmd as new SqlCommand(sql,connection )      
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: [Single argument constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sebfsz50.aspx) expects the text, not the connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = new SqlCommand ();

cmd=(sql,connection);

cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;

Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```